# How msg.sender changes through relaying function calls?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

I'm confused about how `msg.sender` changes through relaying function calls. I know that `msg.sender` sets to the caller(it should be me) address at first, but through the process, `msg.sender` can change to contract address. Like when one contract calls the function of the another contract, then the function of the another contract's `msg.sender` should be the first contract. Now, if like this,

```
contract example1 {
  function A() {
    print msg.sender; // just fake code to imagine it prints out the result
    example2.B();
  }
}

contract example2 {
  function B() {
    print msg.sender; 
    C();
  }
  function C() { print msg.sender; }
}
```

If I call function `A()`, then it will print my address, and followed by the process, `B()` will print contract `example1`'s address. Then is `C()` will print contract `example1`'s address or contract `example2`'s address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Then is C() will print contract example1's address or contract
>   example2's address?

It will print `example1`'s address.
When this code :

```
function B() {
    print msg.sender; 
    C();   }
```

will be executed, VM will read it like this:

```
function B() {
        print msg.sender;
        print msg.sender; // code of C()
}
```

That's why, it will print `example1`'s address.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could I ask you one more thing related about this? But I should change the example though.

Comment: Asking another question will be good as per the community guidelines.