# How msg.sender changes through relaying function calls between contracts?

Tags: solidity, contract-invocation

Here is the example for question.

```
contract example1 {
  function A() {
    print msg.sender; // just fake code to imagine it prints out the result
    example3.C();
  }
}

contract example2 {
  function B() internal {
    print msg.sender; 
  }
}

contract example3 is example2 {
  function C() {
    print msg.sender;
    B();
  }
}
```

If I call function `A()`, then `A()` will print my address, and `C()` will print contract example1's address. Then is `B()` will print contract example1's address or contract example2's address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the Solidity [docs](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.1/contracts.html#inheritance):

> When a contract inherits from other contracts, only a single contract
>   is created on the blockchain, and the code from all the base contracts
>   is compiled into the created contract.

which means code of `example2` will be added in `example3` and example3 will look like:

```
contract example3 {
  function C() {
    print msg.sender;
    B();
  }
function B() internal {
    print msg.sender; 
  }
}
```

So as mentioned [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/63698/how-msg-sender-changes-through-relaying-function-calls), `c()` will print `example1`'s address twice.